# Better way to organize DB relations?

Tags: mysql, performance, relationship, referential-integrity

Lets say I have tables:

1. `company (id, name)`
2. `user (id, username)`
3. `employee (id, user_id, company_id, position) -- position is an integer enum`
4. `department (id, title, company_id)`

And I also need to store relation `user` is a manager of `department`

One `department` may have many `managers`, and `user` may be `manager` in many `departments`

So I have two ways to do that:

1. Make `manager` table look like this: `manager (employee_id, department_id)`
2. Or `manager(user_id, department_id)`

in first case I guarantee integrity (only employee might be a manager), but in order to reach `users` fields from `department` I'll have to do three joins `department` -> `manager` -> `employee` -> `user`.
In second case I have one less join but I have to ensure integrity manually (delete manager, when employee gets deleted etc..)

I can think of another one approach, it's composite keys on `employee` and `manager` tables, but since I work with Doctrine 2 it does not recommend to use it.

So how you think will be better? Or might be something is wrong in the first place? Also where should I lookup next time to be able to solve it by my own? How should I test it?

Comment: You can probably think of another option 3 in which you can add FK in department table which points to user_id which represents manager of that dept.

Comment: One department may has many managers (yep, I forgot to mention it)

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but all employees are users and have a username right? If so, why not just a table 'employees' with username column on it and use the employee_id to get all?

Comment: No employee table have no name field, it's just an intermediate table between user and company, since one user may be an employee of different companies

Comment: Idk it's gonna be duplicating, doesn't seems to be a good idea, and again I have to ensure integrity